# How to route connections to GKE pod through GCI

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-interconnect

We've set up on-premises networks with GCI, the local device is able to ping GKE Node internal IP, but we found the internal IP isn't fixed. So we choose to use GKE Node external IP instead, but I'm not sure if this IP is accessible from local device and if it is, how would it know which pod to route to when connecting to GKE Node external IP?

Do I need to set up something else like NetworkPolicy etc ?

note: we're using GKE autopilot mode

2023/06/06 Updates:

I'm currently attempting to set up an Ingress with an internal IP in Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE), which requires a proxy-only subnet. Additionally, I've tried setting the service type to LoadBalancer (Internal) and assigning a static IP. I also checked advertised IP ranges is on the list of nonMasqueradeCIDRs. However, the results have been unsatisfactory, as on-premises devices are still unable to ping the pods in GKE.

Comment: What's the end goal here?  You want to run an app on GKE and connect to it from from your on-premises network?

Comment: The goal is to let the client ping our pod through interconnect. And pod IP is fixed without changing

Comment: You cannot rely on a persistent pod IP and you should not rely on node IPs either.
The IP addresses for pods are ephemeral; if the pod is restarted, it can be assigned a new address.  Nodes can also upgrades, repaired, etc, which will result in a new node with a new address.

Is there a reason you can't / don't want to use load balancer or at least a FQDN to access the pod(s)?

Comment: @GariSingh the local device can not resolve DNS server and it's out of our control(local device is not our property and it only accept IP address rather than a domain). I found a way to bind internal static IP with LB in ingress you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal IP should only be used if you are using the Private IP of the GKE node and if you are using External IP, issues related to firewall may occur. To overcome this situation, you need to include [Egress NAT policy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/egress-nat-policy-ip-masq-autopilot#:%7E:text=IP%20masquerade%20agent.-,Overview,fixed%20and%20are%20not%20editable.) that will help you to set up SNAT based on pod labels and destination IP address.

The GKE Egress NAT policy lets you configure the IP masquerade behavior for Autopilot clusters.

GKE supports two automatically generated NAT policies, **default policy** and **managed by GKE policy**. The **default policy** is **editable** and it configures the default non-masquerade destinations. All the required changes can be done in the default policy. Follow the steps mentioned in the [official document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/egress-nat-policy-ip-masq-autopilot#:%7E:text=IP%20masquerade%20agent.-,Overview,fixed%20and%20are%20not%20editable.).

When packets are sent to the destinations mentioned in “**CIDR**” under **EgressNATPolicy**, your cluster does not masquerade IP address sources and preserves source Pod IP addresses.

Hope the above information is useful to you.

Comment: on-premises device is like modbus master. it will try to request data to my gke pod. I've tried ingress with internal static IP and service with Internal LoadBalancer. unfortunately not working. on-premises device can't ping the pod.

Comment: @FVBn, If on-premises devices are unable to connect, it could be due to the network issues between on-premises devices and GKE cluster or possibly missing firewall rules at their end.Can you check if the firewall rules are enabled.